# Best way to import Catalogue from Magento to Django Oscar?

Tags: django, magento, django-oscar

I have an existing system in Magento and I'm moving to Django Oscar. Found [this](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto/importing_a_catalogue.html) in the Oscar docs. This works for a certain structure of the `csv` file.

The `csv` export that I get from Magento is totally different. What is the best way to migrate a catalogue from Magento to Oscar ?

Also there is also a 3rd party app [`Oscar Parachute`](https://github.com/tangentlabs/django-oscar-parachute) too which is for migration but I don't know if that works for Magento export.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using the Magento xmlrpc API using [this](https://github.com/bernieke/python-magento) Interface. Works well with some effort.

Comment: How did the transition from Magento to Django go?  I'm considering a similar project for eCommerce site.

Comment: it's a big hassle. Best would be to keep the db schema same(as magento) and write logic in django app. Otherwise you need to write php scripts to export data from magento db in json format and then writing python scripts to insert json data into django db. The db structure of Magento is bit complicated, making the tables flat would work. Once you get all the data in python , slowly change the schema in a more flatter db structure.

Comment: I'm about to undertake the same thing five years later. Plan on merging some ODBC queries (from another system) with Magento API calls and then saving the results into a Django model.  I only care about catalog and customers so it should make my life a bit easier.