# oscarcommerce catalogue import

Tags: python, django, django-oscar, django-import-export

I have a magento2 project. I want to import product catalog in magento 2 into django oscarcommerce. The official documentaion explains an importer (http://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.1/howto/importing_a_catalogue.html). But that they are not supporting because its buggy. I tried to figure out how it works. But I couldn't find the source csv file to test with.

Is there any module/scripts which convert data in magento2 to oscar commerce?
I checked [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32397234/best-way-to-import-catalogue-from-magento-to-django-oscar), but didn't get any idea about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not too difficult to write custom importer code if you check the source code for the django-oscar importer. I have done this myself, and here are the most important steps:

1/ Get or create a ProductClass instance

```
product_class = ProductClass.objects.get_or_create(name='<some_name>')
```

2/ Create a category string for your next product. This string is in the format 'main_category>sub_category>even_deeper_category'. Eg: 'Books>Fiction>Thriller'

```
category_string = create_from_breadcrumbs('some>string>here')
```

3/ Create your product

```
product = Product.objects.get_or_create(upc=upc)

product.product_class = product_class
product.title = ...
...

product.save()
```

4/ Update ProductCategory for this new product (it is made out of a category string and a product)

```
ProductCategory.objects.update_or_create(product=product, category=category_string)
```

5/ Next you need to update Partner info (every product needs a Partner record, this is where the pricing info is stored). If you create the products yourself and don't use partners, just make up some random name.

```
partner = Partner.objects.get_or_create(name='Partner_Name')

importer = CatalogueImporter(logger=None)

importer._create_stockrecord(
        item=product,
        partner_name=partner.name,
        partner_sku='ProductReferenceFromPartner'>,
        price_excl_tax=<SELLING_PRICE>,
        num_in_stock=<STOCK_COUNT>,
        stats=None
        )
```

You can check my source code [here](https://github.com/dentemm/dsshop/tree/310393cefcb36b879b59a78e241fc738f8790a0b/myapps/catalogue/management/commands), but some of it is in Dutch. You can always ask me if you have any questions. I am also using a csv file to populate my database, through a custom Django management command.

Comment: Where should I get the sample .csv file to import data?

Comment: Thanks. How can I install your code in my current oscarcommerce project? Which files I need to copy to my project?

Comment: I do not have any experience with Magento, but I would expect there to be add-ons which will let you export the database to a .csv file.

Comment: I have overridden some of the default Oscar apps, like catalogue, basket and partner (see Oscar docs on overriding existing apps). There I have created a custom management command, but you would need some Django knowledge for this.

Comment: There is no need for me to overriden default oscar apps. Is it required to overridden the default oscar apps to work your code? Can you give me the command to execute the code in terminal?

Comment: Okay, but then you still need to create a custom Django app. I believe this is needed to create a custom management command. Than you need to place this in a Management/Commands/ folder. The name of the command is the name of the file: python manage.py createproducts (createproducts or createproducts2cv depending on which file you are testing)

Comment: Why we create partners in oscarcommerce?

Comment: Partners are linked to stock records. You can setup your catalogue without partners, but if you want to sell products you need at least 1 partner. There can be no stock records without partners.